# pandas drop rows on groupby level 2 sum or mean conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to drop a group (all rows in the group) if the sum of values in a group is equal to a certain value.

The following code provides an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(randn(10,10), index=pd.date_range('20130101',periods=10,freq='T'))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns=['Values'])
>>> df.index.names = ['Time', 'Group']
>>> df.head(12)

                             Values
Time                Group   
2013-01-01 00:00:00   0    0.541795
                      1    0.060798
                      2    0.074224
                      3   -0.006818
                      4    1.211791
                      5   -0.066994
                      6   -1.019984
                      7   -0.558134
                      8    2.006748
                      9    2.737199
2013-01-01 00:01:00   0    1.655502
                      1    0.376214

>>> df['Values'].groupby('Group').sum()

Group
0    3.754481
1   -5.234744
2   -2.000393
3    0.991431
4    3.930547
5   -3.137915
6   -1.260719
7    0.145757
8   -1.832132
9    4.258525
Name: Values, dtype: float64
```

So the question is; how can I for instance drop all group rows where the grouped sum is negative? In my actual dataset I want to drop the groups where the sum or mean is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` + `transform` with `sum`, followed by Boolean indexing:

```
res = df[df.groupby('Group')['Values'].transform('sum') > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration), filtration seems more suitable:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda g: g['Values'].sum() >= 0)
```

---

*(Old answer):*

<s>This worked for me:</s>

```
# Change the index to *just* the `Group` column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index('Group', inplace=True)

# Then create a filter using the groupby object
gb = df['Values'].groupby('Group')
gb_sum = gb.sum()    
val_filter = gb_sum[gb_sum >= 0].index

# Print results
print(df.loc[val_filter])
```

The condition on which you filter can be changed accordingly.